# Which one is more correct to say: "I have never been in prison" or "I have never been to prison"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am aware that when talking talking about visiting or having experience of being in some places, we have to use the preposition *to* with the present perfect. But what about if are talking about being in some some services such school or prison? For example,

> I have never been **in**/**to** prison.
>
> I have never been **in**/**to** university.

Answer (score 2):

When you use **to** with an institution like a prison or a university, it indicates that you were there as one of the people that it's intended for- as an inmate of a prison, or a student of a university. If you worked there as a warder or professor, you would not use **to**.

**in** can be used in the same way about a prison, but not (in UK English) a university or school.

If you want to talk about visiting the physical premises of a type of institution, but not as a student or inmate, you would add an indefinite article, or specify the name of a particular institution:

> I have never been in/into/inside/to **a** prison.
>   I have never been in/into/inside/to **Broadmoor** prison.
>
> I have never been to **a** university
>   I have never been to **Cambridge** university

You would not use in/into/inside for a university because a university is generally made up of several independent buildings. A prison may have multiple buildings, but they are generally all enclosed by one wall or fence.